# Laravel авторизация для сервиса и пользователей

Tags: php, laravel, auth, lumen

Доброго времени суток!

У меня в Laravel приложении есть пользователи, которые могут авторизовываться и администрировать определенные рестораны, выгружать отчеты и прочее действия.

Данные о заказах приходят с ресторана в route вида

`POST http://site.ru/order/create?place_token={secret_token}`

**Проблема:**

Таких роутов порядка 12 штук, присылающих разные данные и везде приходиться заново вызывать сервис PlaceServce и подтягивать объект текущего ресторана по токену, в каждом роуте одно и тоже (DRY....)

Проверку, на то что передается place_token и он валидный, сделал через `Middleware` ,но как иметь доступ к текущему объекту ресторана везде, подобно авторизации пользователей `$request->user()`

Мои мысли - нужно реализовать что-то вроде Auth фасада, в общем хочу узнать как это лучше реализовать...

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [сервисных контейнеров](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container). Если это не получится, вы вполне можете использовать $_GLOBALS в качестве (крайнего) обходного пути

Comment: Можно добавить в middleware, поиск пользователя и потом \Auth::login($user);
Тогда авторизованный пользователь должен быть доступен по \Auth::user();

Comment: @raspberry пользователи отдельно, Места(рестораны) отдельно. у них свое API, свои роуты